# How to rollback a column from a trigger in PL/SQL

Tags: database, plsql, triggers

I have a trigger for my task. I updated my trigger which means I added GL_TP column in my trigger. But before delivering that part I also have to rollback that too for undo that column in my trigger.
So how can I undo GL_TP column in my trigger with sql query?
I am open to every ideas or recommendations?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GL_DEF_TO_TRG
 BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF CDATE, CMPNY_DEF_ID, CUSER, DESCR, GL_DEF_ID, 
  MNY_TP_ID, ST, UDATE, UUSER, GL_TP ON FCBSADM.GL_DEF
   FOR EACH ROW
     DECLARE
     BEGIN
      IF INSERTING THEN
  INSERT INTO MTTFOD.GL_DEF_TO
    (SEQ_GLDEF_ID, GL_DEF_ID, DESCR, MNY_TP_ID, CMPNY_DEF_ID, ST, CDATE, CUSER, UDATE, 
      UUSER, CHANGE_TYPE, CHANGE_DATE, GL_TP)
  VALUES
    (MTTFOD.SEQ_GLDEF_ID.NEXTVAL, :NEW.GL_DEF_ID, :NEW.DESCR, :NEW.MNY_TP_ID, 
    :NEW.CMPNY_DEF_ID, :NEW.ST, :NEW.CDATE, :NEW.CUSER, :NEW.UDATE, :NEW.UUSER, 'I', 
   SYSDATE, :NEW.GL_TP);
ELSIF UPDATING THEN
  INSERT INTO MTTFOD.GL_DEF_TO
    (SEQ_GLDEF_ID, GL_DEF_ID, DESCR, MNY_TP_ID, CMPNY_DEF_ID, ST, CDATE, CUSER, UDATE, 
     UUSER, CHANGE_TYPE, CHANGE_DATE, GL_TP)
  VALUES
    (MTTFOD.SEQ_GLDEF_ID.NEXTVAL, :NEW.GL_DEF_ID, :NEW.DESCR, :NEW.MNY_TP_ID, 
   :NEW.CMPNY_DEF_ID, :NEW.ST, :NEW.CDATE, :NEW.CUSER, :NEW.UDATE, :NEW.UUSER, 'U', 
SYSDATE, 
    NEW:GL_TP);
ELSIF DELETING THEN
  INSERT INTO MTTFOD.GL_DEF_TO
    (SEQ_GLDEF_ID, GL_DEF_ID, DESCR, MNY_TP_ID, CMPNY_DEF_ID, ST, CDATE, CUSER, UDATE, 
      UUSER, CHANGE_TYPE, CHANGE_DATE, GL_TP)
  VALUES
    (MTTFOD.SEQ_GLDEF_ID.NEXTVAL, :OLD.GL_DEF_ID, :OLD.DESCR, :OLD.MNY_TP_ID, 
      :OLD.CMPNY_DEF_ID, :OLD.ST, :OLD.CDATE, :OLD.CUSER, :OLD.UDATE, :OLD.UUSER, 'D', 
    SYSDATE, NEW:GL_TP);
END IF;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'ERROR: CODE:' || SQLCODE || ' MSG:' ||
                         SQLERRM || ' TRACE:' ||
                         SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE(), 1, 3000));
  END;
```

Comment: What is "undo GP_TP column" ? Does that mean the value of GL_TP needs to be set to NULL or that is needs to be set back to the value that it was before the update ?

Comment: @Koen Lostrie it should be removed. From my trigger

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... if it _needs_ to be removed... why don't you just remove it ?

Comment: The previous version of this trigger is that without GL_TP. So in our work, if we deliver a development we should also deliver how to undo things as well. Maybe I didnt explain well the situation so far. I hope it is more clear now ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the statement to _change_ the trigger, correct ? That is not possible with a sql statement - you can only create a trigger with a ```CREATE OR REPLACE trigger``` statement. So to revert to the older version, you'd have to run the previous version of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation is a bit unclear but I'm assuming this is what you are trying to achieve. After the trigger has been executed, set the value of column GL_TP back to the old value:

```
...
    SYSDATE, NEW:GL_TP); --> note the typo here !
  END IF;
  -- to revert the change in GL_TP and set it to the old value
  :NEW.GL_TP := :OLD.GL_TP; 
  -- or you could just set it to NULL like this
  -- :NEW.GL_TP := NULL;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'ERROR: CODE:' || SQLCODE || ' MSG:' ||
                         SQLERRM || ' TRACE:' ||
                         SUBSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE(), 1, 3000));
END;
```

Note that there are several typos in your code. You have `NEW:GL_TP` - that is not valid oracle syntax, it should be `:NEW.GP_TP` instead.

Note that this is NOT rollback. [ROLLBACK](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9021.htm) is a concept in oracle that indicates the undoing of a transaction. There is no such thing as "Rollback of a column".